# Creating osx java app distribution on linux host

Tags: java, linux, macos, jlink

I'm working on a java app (linux, java 10+) that I want to distribute natively in  other platforms. I successfully build a windows dist: jlinked in linux with a java 10+ windows dist, i.e., it created a directory with my module, java.exe and respective dlls (I verified that it worked on windows).

The problem is that when I want build an OSX dist (linux java 10 jlink + OSX java 10 dist), the resulting folder has java linux executable and the **linux SO libraries** instead **osx dylib libs**.

The command line that I'm using is (this is working for linux and windows):

```
${JAVA_HOME}/bin/jlink --compress 2 --no-header-files --module-path target/classes/:"$TARGET_JDK_PATH"/jmods/ --add-modules jdk.crypto.cryptoki,$MODULE_NAME --output $OUTPUT_DIR
```

I tried too

> "$TARGET_JDK_PATH"/Contents/Home/jmods/

Linux and OSX Java version are 11.0.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!

Can't use JDK 10 (jlink) to build a dist with target JDK 11 (jmods). Besides, must specify

> <target.osx.jdk>/Contents/Home/jmods

as "jmods" directory.

Anyway, thank you for the ideas&suggestions.

Comment: Don't forget that you can mark your own answer as accepted here on StackOverflow if it solved your problem :).